# Acessar Propriedade de Objeto com uma string

Tags: c#, reflexão

Aluno:

```
public class Aluno{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Nome { get; set; }
     public string Sobrenome { get; set; }
}
```

Agora preciso acessar o Nome e Sobrenome do aluno através de uma string,
como posso fazer isso?

EX.:

```
string opcaoA = "Nome";

var resultado = Aluno + ".opcaoA ";
//Resultado = "João";
```

Comment: Creio que seja impossível! Atributos de objetos e strings não são equivalentes. C# não é javascript.

Comment: @MichaelPacheco Isso é possível e é muito comum. Se chama reflection.

Comment: @jbueno Muito interessante!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se entendi direito sua dúvida, você pode utilizar Reflection, segue um exemplo prático para te ajudar:

Classe

```
public class Cidade
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

Método Estático para Pegar o valor da Propriedade

```
public static object PegaValorPropriedade(object obj, string propName)
{
    return obj.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(obj, null);
}
```

Página

```
protected  void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var cid = new Cidade();
    cid.Nome = "Jose";
    object ed = PegaValorPropriedade(cid, "Nome");
    Response.Write(ed.ToString());
    //Imprime José
}
```

Comment: Perfeito amigo! Nossa, faz tempo que estou tentando resolver esse problema! Ajudou de ++ Obrigado!

Comment: Show, não esqueça de avaliar e fechar a questão. ;)